# .NET how can I continually send and receive 600k byte chunks through Windows virtual COM port?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, serial-port

My present method has a problem streaming from my .NET transmit app to my .NET receive app, both running on the same computer.

Here's my method...

My 1st .NET app, for transmitting, sends 600KB:

```
MyVirtualTxCOMport.Write( buf, 0 600000 )
```

But my 2nd app each call to .Read reads a small chunk of no more than around 10 bytes.

```
dim packet_buffer( 600000  ) as Byte
buffer_index = 0
total_bytes_read = 0
Do
    bytes_to_read = 600000   -   total_bytes_read
    buffer_index =   total_bytes_read
    bytes_read =  MyVirtualRxCOMport.Read( packet_buffer, buffer_index, bytes_to_read )
    total_bytes_read  +=  bytes_read
    if total_bytes_read  <   600000 
        Continue do
    ELSE
        Exit do
    End If
Loop
```

Summary of Setup:

```
On my Windows 10 computer:  
1st app ==> 9600 baud COM3 virtual port 
    ==> USB/serial adapter 
    ==> serial cable 
    ==> 2nd USB/serial adapter 
    ==> COM4 
    ==> 2nd app
```

Both apps are running on my desktop Windows 10 64-bit computer.  1st app transmits out virtual COM port COM3 through USB/serial adapter, through the serial cable to the same model of serial/USB adapter, to its virtual COM port COM4, to 2nd .NET app.
 (serial/USB adapter is Amazon Choice Sabrent 1Mbps)

(This is to test out the eventual real-time stream from embedded processor through its UART to an external serial/USB adapter (sparkFun adapter that uses FT232RL IC from FTDI), to Windows 10 .NET GUI.)

Comment: The UART in the PC only has a small buffer.  You need to use Asynchronous Read to get all the data.

Comment: Both of my apps each launch a thread to tx and rx the serial I/O.  Is there another advantage to Asynch Read other than not blocking UI thread?

Comment: Yes.  You can easily get a Overflow error from UART if you don't read the data quickly.  You can't control the task swapping on the PC and if another task runs to long you application will not be able to read data quick enough.  Asynchronous reads uses windows events which will prevent the overflow.  I've been having this issues with PC for 40 years.  Always use Asynchronous method for read streams, ports, and sockets.

Comment: Ah!  Another old-timer.  I will therefore heed your sage advice, sir, and asynch my way into serial bliss.  :-)

Comment: Will it also help to use XONXOF flow control (and adding escape encoding for XON and XOFF)?  I'm going through virtual COM ports and USB/serial adapters, and so assume HW flow control won't work.

Comment: Archaic.  Nobody uses flow control any more.